# Can anyone recommend a REST / SOAP Web Service for VIN Numbers?

Tags: xml, rest, soap, vin

I'm developing a website for a small used car dealership with a need for VIN decoding. Given as much, I'm looking for maybe 1,000 - 1,500 requests for VINs per year. Does anyone have experience with a price-efficient web service to deliver such data?

Comment: VIN databases tend to be specific to continent/region. You might want to specify which one you are interested in.

Comment: Vehicle Identification Number.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_Identification_Number

Comment: I would suggest http://vinquery.com/. This has lite, basic, standard and extended reports for your need.

Comment: Why is this closed as not constructive? Actually, really helps me to find 2 web services I never heard about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try ask at [Vin-info.com](http://vin-info.com) - there is vin decoder and I've heard, that they are preparing API

Comment: The link is no longer available

Comment: Edmunds has an actual legit api. http://developer.edmunds.com/api-documentation/vehicle/spec_vin_decoding/v2/

Comment: http://uk.vin-info.com/ does not have any api support.  I am using edmunds, it is free.

Comment: https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/ is one option.

Comment: Worth mentioning that vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api is only useful for the USA.

Answer (score 6):

A couple other options are available as well.

- http://www.vinlink.com/
- http://www.vinquery.com/

  - Detailed API with a number of different options.
- http://vinapi.skizmo.com/

  - This option is pretty inexpensive if you just need basic information.

Comment: Do you happen to know if vinapi can be used with client side ajax?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think you can use curl with client side ajax.  If so, this may work [link](http://vinapi.skizmo.com/examples#curl)

Comment: http://vinapi.skizmo.com/ Doesn't seem to be working anymore

Comment: And http://www.vinquery.com/ only covers the United States and Canada.

Answer (score 4):

DataOne Software (the company I work for) has a REST web service for decoding VINs. Our data covers model years 1981-present. For the volume you're talking about pricing would be very inexpensive, and we offer a free trial.

http://www.dataonesoftware.com/web-services-vin-decoder-api

Comment: Except they ask a thousand questions before you can access that api and they require a phone number. However, I did get confirmation pretty quickly. 3-5 minutes.

Comment: @Kelvin Thanks for the feedback on the form. We try not to ask more than we need in order to differentiate serious users from spammers, but I've passed your feedback along to our marketing team. I'm glad to hear you got confirmation quickly. Please feel free to send me a DM if you need  help with anything!